# nice space with wild fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I would like to know an example of nice space with very strange fundamental group. With simplices and similar things I only get finitely presented groups.

Edit. I know from comments that Hawaiian earring has uncountable fundamental group. This shows that it is not a simplicial complex with one edge for every "loop". This contrasts the intuition given by its picture.

What is the intuitive reason for the Hawaiian earring not to be a simplicial complex?

Comment: The [Hawaiian earring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring)?

Comment: Why it is wild?

Comment: How do you define wild?

Comment: Its fundamental group is not $\mathbb z^\infty$?

Comment: No. It's more complicated than that. Check out the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Nice example, although I'm not sure if the Hawaiian earring counts as a "nice" space.  But then again is it really possible to be "nice" and have a crazy fundamental group?

Comment: Is that a simplicial complex?

Comment: How about [$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67549/fundamental-group-of-r2-q2)?

Comment: Simplicial complex do have always "tame" fundamental group?

Comment: Please define tame.

Comment: Tame could be e.g. countable

Comment: @user3474383 You really need to define these terms (tame, wild, etc) for this question to be answerable.

Comment: Is it true that a simplicial complex has countable fundamental group?

Comment: If the simplicial complex is finite, then yes, as you can describe its fundamental group by a finite set of generator and finitely many relations. (why close this question, I think it is nice and natural)

Comment: @user3474383: For every group $G$ there's a simplicial complex $BG$ such that $\pi_1(BG) = G$. It's called "the" classifying space of $G$.

Comment: The Hawiian hearring is not "the simplicial complex you immagine" because the topology of a simplicial complex is that induced by the piecewise euclidean metric. The loops of the H.H. become smaller and smaller when you approach to zero. In fact, as set, the H.H. "is" the wedge of countably many circles, but the topology is different. If you give the H.H. the topology of an infinite wedge, then its fundamental group becames countable because a CONTINUOUS map from $S^1$ to the H.H. can wrap only finitely many circles.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dichotomy for fundamental groups of locally path connected, compact metric spaces (called Peano continua).

**Theorem (Shelah/Eda):** If $X$ is a locally path connected, compact metric space, then either

1) $X$ is semilocally simply connected and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is finitely presented

or

2) $X$ is NOT semilocally simply connected and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is uncountable (and typically pretty wild).

It is pretty interesting that there is no room in the middle for fundamental groups with countably infinite generators. To address your specific question, every simplicial complex is semilocally simply connected. Since the Hawaiian earring does not have this property, it cannot be (or even have the same homotopy type as) a simplicial complex (finite or infinite)

**Examples:**

- Any finite simplicial complex satisfies (1)
- The Hawaiian earring (along with the Sierpinski carpet and Menger curve) satisfies (2) and has a wild fundamental group
- The infinite torus $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}S^1$ satisfies (2) and has
  fundamental group $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}$. This group -
  called the Specker group- is uncountable but the algebraic structure
  is not quite as wild.

If you are interested in understanding the "wildness" of the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring, I give an introduction to it in this blog post:

http://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/the-hawaiian-earring/

Another easy-to-construct space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has a "wild" fundamental group is the harmonic archipelago, which I describe in another blog post:

http://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/the-harmonic-archipelago/